# Architecture of a single page javascript application with sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture, publish-subscribe

Currently I have a simple, single page app set up called `App`. What I am attempting to do is make 'sections' of the website that have animations that occur when each section is loaded, and a set of different animations that happen when a new section is navigated to (unload animation for the current section).

My code looks like this:

```
var App = {
    init: function() {
        // Do initial set up
        this.navButtons();
    },
    navButtons: {
        $('.nav li').on('click', function(){
            var section = $(this).data('section');
            App[section + 'Section'].unload(App[section + 'Section'].init);
        });
    },
    homeSection: {
        init: function() {
            // Do init animations here
        },
        unload: function(callback) {
            // Do unload animations here
            if(typeof callback === 'function') callback()
        }
    },
    storySection: {
        init: function() {
            // Do init animations here
        },
        unload: function(callback) {
            // Do unload animations here
            if(typeof callback === 'function') callback()
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the way the app works is, you click a navigation button, and it loads the appropriate section by doing a `App[section + 'Section'].init()` on click. This causes the correct section to load and the correct animation to fire. However, I'm trying to add an `unload` function that will happen **prior** to loading the next section. I tried doing this by using a callback: `App[section + 'Section'].unload(App[section + 'Section'])`, but this doesn't actually work.

With my current knowledge this was the best idea I could come up with. Is there a better design pattern that I could use to handle loading/unloading sections that wait until that event actually happens? Possibly pub/sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're calling the load and unload function on the same section, change your click event to this:

```
navButtons: function () {
        var lastSection = null;
        $('.nav li').on('click', function(){
            var section = $(this).data('section');
            App[(lastSection || 'dummy')+ 'Section'].unload(App[section + 'Section'].init);
            lastSection = section;
        });
    },
```

then add a dummy section unload function for first invocation:

```
dummySection: {
    unload: function(callback) { callback(); }
},
```

What this does is keep the last section called available to the next click event. This is thanks to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), which basically means the `lastSection` variable retains its state across all invocations of the click event function, because they're declared in the same scope.